# ElasticSearch JarHell com.esotericsoftware.minlog.Log$Logger

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-storm, kryo

I need to write an elastic-search bolt using node-client in Storm.

I do not want to use Transport-client because that is less efficient (involves one extra hop between nodes).

So I try to build my own ES bolt using the following code:

```
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {

  Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
    .put("http.enabled", false)
    .put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", false)
    .put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts", hosts)
    .put("discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes", 1)
    .put("path.home", pathHome)
    .build();

  client = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
    .settings(settings)
    .clusterName(esCluster)
    .data(false)
    .client(true)
    .node().client();
}
```

The above method in my elastic-search-bolt gives the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load bundle [file:/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-2.2.0/modules/lang-expression/antlr4-runtime-4.5.1-1.jar, file:/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-2.2.0/modules/lang-expression/asm-5.0.4.jar, file:/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-2.2.0/modules/lang-expression/asm-commons-5.0.4.jar, file:/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-2.2.0/modules/lang-expression/lang-expression-2.2.0.jar, file:/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-2.2.0/modules/lang-expression/lucene-expressions-5.4.1.jar] due to jar hell

    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:421) ~[storm_es_bolt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:115) ~[storm_es_bolt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:146) ~[storm_es_bolt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:128) ~[storm_es_bolt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:145) ~[storm_es_bolt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:152) ~[storm_es_bolt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at mypkg.storm.NodeClientBolt.prepare(NodeClientBolt.java:89) ~[storm_es_bolt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5694$fn__5707.invoke(executor.clj:757) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:477) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_71]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!

class: com.esotericsoftware.minlog.Log$Logger
jar1: /etc/storm/storm-0.10.0.nimbus/lib/kryo-2.21.jar
jar2: /etc/storm/storm-0.10.0.nimbus/lib/minlog-1.2.jar

    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkClass(JarHell.java:280) ~[storm_es_bolt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:186) ~[storm_es_bolt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:419) ~[storm_es_bolt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    ... 10 more
```

EDIT:
The above problem is fixed with Jeremie's good suggestion, but then I run into another one (very similar):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
class: org.objectweb.asm.AnnotationVisitor
jar1: /etc/storm/storm-0.10.0.nimbus/lib/asm-4.0.jar
jar2: /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-2.2.0/modules/lang-expression/asm-5.0.4.jar
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkClass(JarHell.java:280) ~[storm_hello_world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:186) ~[storm_hello_world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:419) ~[storm_hello_world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
... 10 more
```

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Kryo 2.21 embed (through the shade plugin) the library `minlog`. You can safely remove this jar from your distribution (`/etc/storm/storm-0.10.0.nimbus/lib/minlog-1.2.jar`)

The embedding of his dependencies has been removed in Kryo 3.x

Comment: Thank you Jeremie, but I run into another similar problem that I have updated in the question above. Appreciate your help.

Comment: remove the oldest library (here asm-4.0), and just try. There is nothing to do other than that. This exception means you have two versions of the same library, you must choose which library to keep, and hope there isn't any incompatibilities